# Informatica session properties

Tags: database, informatica

if by default a target based commit is enabled in informatica and the size of the writer buffer is ~10,700 rows?
Does this mean that if -
Source table has 10 records and 10 records are loaded into my target table then until i fire commit command in my database manually, all of the data from the target table will be lost as soon as i disconnect from my database?

Comment: Have you tested?

Answer (score 1):

Default target based commit point is 10,000. This means,

- if you have 10 rows going to target, data will be committed after 10th
  row in target.
- if you have 10,000 rows going to target, data will be committed
  after 10,000th row.
- if you have 10,005 rows going to target, data
  will be first committed after 10,000th row, then another and last
  commit will be after 5th row.

Target based commit doesn't depend on source rows.